# addition of row ID in JqueryDatatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I have this datatable using jQuery filled by Ajax data source (arrays)

```
<script>
    var dataSet = [
                ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X','Win 95+','4','X'],
                ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C','Win 95+','4','X'],
                ['Other browsers','All others','-','-','U','Win 95+','4','X']
               ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable;


        oTable = $('#applicationsDatatable').dataTable( {
            "data": dataSet,
            "sScrollY": "auto",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
            "aoColumns": [
                        { "bSortable": false },
                        null,null,null,null,null,null,null
            ],
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "bSortCellsTop": true,
            "sDom": 'tlpi<"clear">'
        });      
    } );

</script>





<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display normaltable" id="applicationsDatatable" >
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>header1</th>
    <th>header2</th>
    <th>header3</th>
    <th>header4</th>    
    <th>header5</th>
    <th>header6</th>
    <th>header7</th>
    <th>header8</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${appList}" var="item" varStatus="rowIndex">
    <tr id="${item.id}">
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I would like to assign an ID in every row, that I assign when creating the table,
but I get 'undefined' trying to acces the ID when I click on the row

```
$('#applicationsDatatable').delegate("tr", "click", function() {                    
        alert ($(this).attr("id"));             
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a created row callback could work. This way you can assign an id to each row of your datatable.

```
"createdRow" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) 
{
$(nRow).attr('id', 'row' + (iDisplayIndex + 1));
}
```

If this works you should be able to access the id element of the row as you have already done.

Look here for reference.

> https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow
>
> https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback